# List of Figures page Margins

Tags: table-of-contents, margins

I am writing my dissertation and I have to follow certain graduate school guidelines to submit my dissertation successfully. One rule that the graduate school has is that all margins on each page should be the fixed 1" value. Currently, different sections of my dissertation follow this rule except for the List of Figures page. Is there a way that I can fix the margins on this page WITHOUT affecting margins of other pages?

Answer (score 2):

Seems I found a solution. For fixing the left margin do this:

search for:

\newcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}

in the style file. The length 1.5em is the space from the left margin to every line in the list of figures, whereas 2.3em is the space reserved for the number of every figure. You can read the following too:
http://www.latex-community.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=817